# How to split this string and get the number separately in ios regular expression

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have a `NSString`like this "media_w940996738_476.mp3" I want to get this "476" number separately. How can I get it from this NSString using a regular expression.

Comment: Are all the strings are of similar names as "media_w123456789_123.mp3" ???

Comment: yeas only the number will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to find out last value separated by underscore before file extension, use following code:

```
NSString *mediaName = [[fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] firstObject];
int requiredNumber = [[[mediaName componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] lastObject] intValue];
```

Comment: Correct answer, but where is regex?

Comment: Best code is always simple and efficient.. Why explicitly use regex if it can be done in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is your regex. for this

NSString *yourString = @"media_w940996738_476.mp3";
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]{3})([.]{1})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];


[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

    // detect
    NSString *insideString = [yourString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

    //print
    NSLog(@"%@",insideString);

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do with regex:

```
NSString *string = @"media_w940996738_476.mp3";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"_([:digit:]+)\\." options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        // detect
        NSString *insideString = [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]];
        //print
        NSLog(@"%@",insideString);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ***don't absolutely need a regex***, you can simply use the following :

```
NSInteger value = [[[fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] lastObject] integerValue];
```

Calling `componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"` will return an array, and the `lastObject` will be `476.mp3`.

Getting the `integerValue` on it should return `476`.

Answer (score 0):

With regex you could search for *one or more digits* `(\d)+` *ending with .mp3* `(\.mp3)$`:

```
NSString *filename = @"media_w940996738_476.mp3";

NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+)(\\.mp3)$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, filename.length);
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [[regex matchesInString:filename options:0 range:textRange] firstObject];
NSString *matchedString = [filename substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@", matchedString);
```

If you want to match filenames with different extensions you can change the regex pattern by listing them:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+)(\\.(mp3|m4a|m4b|aa))$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

To match any filename with 2 or 3 character extension:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d+)(\\.\\b\\w{2,3})$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```